# getting list of maximum values in sql

Tags: sql, mysql

I am working with mysql. I need queries  that fetch a list of maximum values.

I know how to get one maximum value i.e using max(colName) in select query.

Is there some similar query that can fetch more than 1 maximum values like the top 10 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table order by colName desc limit 10;
```

Comment: what if colName is having same values? You need to apply distinct to it.

Comment: I think he want top 10 max value rows

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER by price DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select distinct colName from tablename order by colName desc limit 10;
```

Comment: but then both the entries have to included. as both are in maximum list.

Comment: i am sorry but can u give more explanation. Which are two entries u r taking about. As per my understanding i got only colName , which is other?

Comment: @Nik: He wants top 10 rows not distinct values of column

Comment: @Shakti: But he didn't mention a single word about rows. You might be right.

Comment: @nik: its as shakti said. if i the column is salary then i want both people with salary 100,000 to be selected. to my understanding using distinct will give only one entry with 100,000. but thanks anyways.

Comment: @SonOfTheEARTh: So you mean to say that u want top 10 salaries, right or all the people with maximum salary or all the people with max top 10 salaries. Please clarify.

Comment: it is about people with maximum salaries